# How can I use non Steam workshop mods in Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I have Euro Truck Simulator 2, and I got it from steam.
I want to use my mods that I have downloaded from ETS2.LT they're .scs files.
I do not have a "mods" folder so I made one and put the .scs files in there, and then I opened ETS2 and nothing.

So how can I get the non workshop mods to work?

Answer (score 4):

Put the mods in the "mod" folder in `My Documents/Euro Truck Simulator 2` (not "mod**s**") and the mods will work.